# Formbuild with Pylons?

Tags: python, pylons

Is using formbuild with pylons, when you have pretty customized needs, actually easier than manually creating your own form html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really prefer plain html, but it's super easy 
populate a select with a syntax like this:

```
def foo(self):
    c.countries = Model.get(Country)....
return Render('foo.html')
```

Template:

```
${h.field(
    "Country:",
    h.select(
    "country",
    id='country',
    options = c.countries,
    selected_values=[],
    required=True,
 ),
)}
```

also custom validation it's handled pretty well along with FormEncode

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm just going to use plain HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

That would be bad if you use many forms of

I suggest using Pylons with WTForm

To cope with WTForm create a separate class, for example, a Layout that will handle all of the fields in the form of a uniform standard adopted by your site.

This is very good to make the processing of forms in a separate class because they do not have to redo all the forms will only need to change the layout of the base class